# OnePageScroll normal scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am using One page scroll script (from http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html).
It works perfectly, click on menu item takes me to wanted div/section with nice effect.

Bad thing is that it also disables "normal" scrolling, aka. when i scroll down once, i am automatically taken to the next section, and i would like it to act normally so that i can scroll down to where i need.

I have dig thru the .js file, but i simply cant find where i can disable this.
I am not very familiar with jQuery, so if anybody can advise something, it would be awesome.

Can anybody advise something? http://jsfiddle.net/yeP9b

```
/* ===========================================================
 * jquery-onepage-scroll.js v1
 * ===========================================================
 * Copyright 2013 Pete Rojwongsuriya.
 * http://www.thepetedesign.com
 *
 * Create an Apple-like website that let user scroll
 * one page at a time
 *
 * Credit: Eike Send for the awesome swipe event
 * https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll
 *
 * ========================================================== */
```

Thank you